# В чем смысл геттеров и сеттеров?

Tags: c#, инкапсуляция

Я недавно начал изучать C#. Делаю я это для того, чтобы создавать игры на мобильные устройства (мне это просто интересно). Вот недавно я встретился с таким понятием как get и set. Но я не понимаю, зачем надо давать полю private, а потом возвращать значение. Разве это не делает то же самое, что и поле public? Просто я уже довольно много прочитал на эту тему, но так и не понял нужна ли инкапсуляция вообще?